# How to store the result of a huggingface pipeline as correct JSON?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, machine-learning, huggingface-transformers

I have a huggingface pipeline that classifies tokens, like this:

```
words_input_dir = "MYDIRECTORY OF TXT FILES"
os.chdir(words_input_dir)

resu = {}
sents = []
label_list= ['literal',"metaphoric"]
label_dict_relations={ i : l for i, l in enumerate(label_list) }
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("lwachowiak/Metaphor-Detection-XLMR")

model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("lwachowiak/Metaphor-Detection-XLMR", id2label=label_dict_relations)
for filename in os.listdir(words_input_dir):
    if filename.endswith(".xml"):
      tree = ET.parse(filename)
      root = tree.getroot()
      node = root.findall("./body/sec/p")
      for x in node:
        if x is not None:
          coco = x.text
          nerpipeline = pipeline('ner', model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, aggregation_strategy="simple")
          data = nerpipeline(str(coco))
          sents.append(data)
      resu[filename] = {"sentence": sents} #this is the supposed json
```

The problem is that the supposed json resulting from this is very problematic, it has single quotes and things like that. "data", so the output of the pipeline, is a list of lists with dictionaries inside. One list looks like this, and to store them all from the for loop I use the sents list to append all the lists inside:

```
[{'end': 11,
  'entity_group': 'l',
  'score': 0.99962264,
  'start': 0,
  'word': 'Our love is'},
 {'end': 25,
  'entity_group': 'metaphoric',
  'score': 0.9950348,
  'start': 12,
  'word': 'at crossroads'},
 {'end': 44,
  'entity_group': 'l',
  'score': 0.99978614,
  'start': 26,
  'word': 'and the company is'},
 {'end': 67,
  'entity_group': 'metaphoric',
  'score': 0.86717546,
  'start': 45,
  'word': 'going into hibernation'}]
```

I'd like to have a JSON so that I can manipulate it.